# RestAssured delete method returns status code 405

Tags: rest-assured, http-delete

RestAssured Delete method returns status code as 405 but when I try from Postman it returns 202 ( which is as expected )

In Postman :

Method : DELETE

PATH : .../rest/end1/end2?name=xyz

Code :

```
String name = "xyz";

String baseURI = System.getProperty("environmentPathUrl");

String path = "/rest/end1";

    public void deleteName(String baseURI, String path, String name) {
    String Resp = RestAssured.given().baseUri(baseURI).basePath(path).queryParam("name", name).when()
            .delete("/end2").then().assertThat().statusCode(202).and().extract().response().asString();

    System.out.println("Response is\t" + Resp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake in the Rest Assured code, Add a `.log().all()` after `given()` to see the request traffic and you will be able to see your mistake

I've made few changes to the code and this should work for you hopefully

```
public static void deleteName() {

    String name = "xyz";
    String baseURI = System.getProperty("environmentPathUrl");
    String path = "/rest/end1";

    String Resp = RestAssured.given().log().all().baseUri(baseURI).basePath(path).queryParam("name", name).when()
            .delete("/end2").then().assertThat().statusCode(202).and().extract().response().asString();

    System.out.println("Response is\t" + Resp);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    deleteName();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately,i haven't found mistake in my code. Your changes doesn't apply to logic change. Can i have some hint from you if you see where is my problem?

Comment: yes, I did. I still can't figure it out. RequestURI is OK, method OK, other parameters are none. This is the problem?

Comment: problem not solved, but I learned how to debug. Thanks :)

Comment: I resolved my problem. I got expected 202. So i understand that request should be effective- the object should be deleted after some time,right?

Comment: and I'd be very interested to know :) what was it ?

Comment: lack of spacebar between "Bearer" and token

Comment: Can you please answear my question: that request should be effective- the object should be deleted after some time,right?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you elaborate pls

Comment: As i make this request from Postman it is effective- the name  is deleted successfully after a while from the list But when i run this method from IntelliJ(with response froms server 202) I still see the name on the list. I have thought that delete action wll be performed after running this method,but it does't seem to

Comment: so, where can I for for failure of operation?